# Words containing consecutive and nonconsecutive elements.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose, you're given a set of letters $A$, $B$ and $C$. Then find the number of eight-letter words that contain:

1. Exactly $3$ $A$s.
2. $3$ $A$s with exactly $2$ consecutive $A$s.
3. $3$ $A$s with at least $2$ consecutive $A$s.

I'm not sure if I did them right. My solutions:

1. The number of words with exactly $3$ $A$s = ${\binom{8}{3}}.2^5$.
2. The number of words with exactly $2$ consecutive $A$s = ${\binom{5}{1}}*{\binom{4}{1}}*2^5 + {\binom{2}{1}}*{\binom{5}{1}}*2^5$.
3. The number of words with at least $2$ consecutive $A$s = ${\binom{5}{1}}*{\binom{4}{1}}*2^5 + {\binom{2}{1}}*{\binom{5}{1}}*2^5 + {\binom{6}{1}}*2^5$.

Comment: Share your own efforts on this. In the question (not in a comment).

Comment: Is it okay now?

Answer (score 0):

1. Exactly $3$ A's, chose any 3 out of 8 positions put A in them and in rest of 5 positions only fill using B or C thus $A_1=\binom{8}{3}*2^5$
2. 3 A's with exactly 2 consecutive say first 2 are in position 1 and 2 then third can't 
   in position 3 , if 2 are in last two positions then third A can't be in third last.For   every other two consecutive positions , third A could not be put in 2 positions.So
   $A_2=2*\binom{5}{1}*2^5+5*\binom{4}{1}*2^5$.
3. 3 A's with at least 2 consecutive = 3 A's all consecutive + 3A's exactly 2 consecutive.
   second we have already calculated.Thus 3 A's all consecutive $\binom{6}{1}*2^5$.
   Thus at least two consecutive $A_3=A_2+\binom{6}{1}*2^5$.

Comment: shouldn't the answer to the second question be $2 * {\binom{5}{1}} * 2^5 + 5 * {\binom{4}{1}} * 2^5$ ?

Comment: oops sorry yeah

Comment: I don't understand your answer to the third question. I think the number of words where all $3$ $A$s are consecutive is ${\binom{6}{1}}*2^5$. So the answer should be ${\binom{6}{1}}*2^5 + A_2$. 

Can you explain your solution?

Comment: i keep on making silly mistakes :)